# Angular-cli "ng serve" error

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angularfire2

when I am trying to do ng serve I recieve this error:
"core_1.Version is not a constructor".
I have attached the error log if that will help. It seems like the problem is associated to angularfire2 but I am not 100% sure. I have the latest version of angular-cli and angularfire2. I tried to use some older versions but it just was not working for me. If any one has any ideas it would be a huge help thank you!

[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsqS9.png)

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue was reported. See if using @angular/compiler-cli version 2.2.4 will help:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13342